# How connect to Html page with node.js server and aws virtual machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, twitter

I'm trying to install a node.js server for a sentiment analysis service with my Twitter account that retrieve the tweets on my profile and provides a statistical output and saves them on a Mongo db istance.
I have uploaded my node.js code on an AWS virtual machine with an public IP address and with the permission to create an endpoint with HTTP and HTTPS protocols.
I have installed successfully the node.js code on AWS virtual machine with Windows Server 2019 OS, with the npm install -g -n command with 0 dependencies errors, and when I try to connect to the AWS virtual machine with http://ip_public_address:8080 I get the error "impossible to connect - err-connection_timeout".

This is the link to the github project that I need to install and to work on AWS virtual machine:
https://github.com/thisandagain/sentiment

Maybe I am confused about how to connect with the index.html page via AWS virtual machine and I don't know if this page must be retrieved with a IP public address or localhost parameter and what is required, at node.js level code, in order to enable the AWS virtual machine to respond to my browser with the content of index.html page.

Please can you give me advices about to implement successfully this project?

Thanks

Filippo

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention [security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/working-with-security-groups.html) in your question at all, so the likely cause is that you never opened port `8080` in the security group assigned to the EC2 instance. You may also need to open that port in the Windows firewall on that server.